# Layout page not found executing a sample ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

> The layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" could not be found at
>   the following path: "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".

I am getting the above error from the `_ViewState.cshtml`

It was coming while I execute it through my Home Controller.

I have got to see some link for resolving this program but it is not happening. Could you people help me out on this

Comment: Make sure the layout file does in fact exist in the expected location. Post your _ViewState.cshtml file.

Comment: Hi mxmissile
here is data from the _ViewState.cshtml file
 
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what is the problem.

Check the `Views/Shared` Folder and make sure the `_Layout.cshtml` is actually there.

The build action of that file should be `Content`

Answer (score 1):

If you have your code like this

```
@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "title"; 
Layout = "_Layout"; 
}
```

Then make sure that in your ~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml file you have set the correct path

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```